# Difference between UPDATE and EDIT in Cakephp RESTful configuration

Tags: rest, cakephp

I'm refering to this page of the [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

Which is the difference between the action "edit" made with method "PUT" and the action "update" made with the action "POST"?

As far as I got, It's up to me whether implement one or the other, this mapping covers the totality of the cases. These methods are overall equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. It's just an example to show how you can setup custom REST routes. Normally you would only map one of them in your app.